# Insert null into sql alchemy datetime

Tags: sqlalchemy, null, insert, migration, flask-sqlalchemy

I am doing a migration where I have a table A that I'm splitting into table B and C. My (simplified) migration script is :

```
from alembic import op

con = op.get_bind()
items = con.execute("SELECT * FROM public.A")
for item in items:
    B_id = item.b
    C_id = item.c
    some_attributes = item.some_attributes
    some_other_attributes = item.some_other_attributes
    created_at = item.created_at
    updated_at = created_at
    if item.deleted:             
        deleted_at = created_at
    else:
        deleted_at = created_at     # This should be None
    
    op.execute("INSERT INTO B (id, some_attributes, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at)\
                VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')\
                ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING".format(B_id, some_attributes, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at))

    op.execute("INSERT INTO C (id, some_other_attributes ,created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, B_id)\
                VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(C_id,some_other_attributes,created_at,updated_at,deleted_at,B_id))
```

For now this works but the thing is that when my item is not deleted I would like my `deleted_at` to be set to `NULL`. The thing is that if I set the value to None, `"NULL"`, `"null"` or even `sqlalchemy.sql.null()` I get this error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat) invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NULL"
```

My column is nullable, I can do what I want by duplicating my code in the if `item.deleted` statement and not mention the `deleted _at` column when I want to set it to null but that's not very elegant at all.

I could also import A, B and C from my models and create a new instance of B and C each time and add then commit each one to my session, but this would require me to change B and C init code and that feels wrong to me to do so just for migration sake.

Does anyone have any idea for me ? Tell me if I need to edit anything to add precisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it with this approach :

> I could also import A, B and C from my models and create a new instance of B and C each time and add then commit each one to my session, but this would require me to change B and C init code and that feels wrong to me to do so just for migration sake.

But instead of changing the init code for B and C i just did this :

```
b = B(some_attributes,created_at)
b.deleted_at = deleted_at
session.add(b)
session.commit()
```